# Trying to access an element in an array that is in an array

Tags: php

I'm currently working with google places api and it returns the json in the quote. I'm trying to access the "photo_reference" element in the "photos" array and I've been using the attached code but it keeps returning null and I can't figure out why(`$response` is where I stored my json).

```
$response["results"][1]["photos"]["photo_reference"];
```

```
"results" : [
  {
     "formatted_address" : "525 W 28th St, Los Angeles, CA 90007, USA",
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 34.0265698,
           "lng" : -118.2766572
        },
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 34.02787052989272,
              "lng" : -118.2752304701073
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 34.02517087010728,
              "lng" : -118.2779301298927
           }
        }
     },
     "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
     "id" : "73f56efe009cf4f46fab07e380e89fb1024f2dda",
     "name" : "Grinder",
     "opening_hours" : {
        "open_now" : true
     },
     "photos" : [
        {
           "height" : 1080,
           "html_attributions" : [
              "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/111289966799928187791/photos\"\u003eRomeo C\u003c/a\u003e"
           ],
           "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAAYZeA7hp-fV6SUytgcjrEbTeOTDarmxhYYUoOUixAKCMhsJGyQdSnTl_LYmBGfcGjH44BfLmDJDV325flXgjCMHa8WCsKFBciYUT6hYUG0YesO5FxkClNpSDH-gPjOj5kEhBYB8hWZbWG-o20qvN9mfwiGhROzzx8GZWVS17R5NOBx7ZiJUTEug",
           "width" : 1920
        }
     ],
     "place_id" : "ChIJGZfInOfHwoARtMA9n87JMK8",
     "plus_code" : {
        "compound_code" : "2PGF+J8 Los Angeles, California, USA",
        "global_code" : "85632PGF+J8"
     },
     "price_level" : 1,
     "rating" : 4.3,
     "reference" : "ChIJGZfInOfHwoARtMA9n87JMK8",
     "types" : [ "restaurant", "point_of_interest", "food", "establishment" ],
     "user_ratings_total" : 645
  },
```

Comment: You need to decode it first, `json_decore($jsonString);`

Comment: Already did that in line prior: $response = json_decode($response, true);

Comment: Then `var_dump($response);` and see what it outputs.

Comment: Also, note that PHP is zero-indexed - meaning that the first element in an array is 0, not 1.

Comment: It returns the quote that I attached

Comment: Also looks like `["photos"]` has a sub array so try `$response["results"][0]["photos"][0]["photo_reference"]`

Comment: @NigelRen that worked, thanks!

Comment: echo "<pre>"; print_r(json_decode($response, true));

Comment: in "photos" key you get array [array] so you need to pass [0] before photo_reference key like:  $response["results"][0]["photos"][0]["photo_reference"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `["photos"]` has a sub array you need to use...

```
 $response["results"][0]["photos"][0]["photo_reference"]
```

It's always worth using `print_r()` and following the structure through to work out where the various arrays sit.